# Processing - Basic! Ellipse getting progressively smaller using loop

Tags: loops, for-loop, while-loop, processing, ellipse

I'm just learning the basics of Processing and I'm stuck with loops. How do I make a line of ellipses (maybe 7?) get progressively smaller and still have them attached?

This is the code so far but it's not working!

```
size (400,400);
float y=200;

for(int x=20; x<100; x=x+20) {
    for (int size=40; size<100; size=size-5) {
        ellipse (x,y,size,size); 
        x=x+20; 
    }
}
```

Also, another question! Here is a grid of crosses in circles. Using a loop, how do I get a row of five, followed by a row of four underneath, then three etc.

```
int x=20;
int y=30;
size(100,100); //set size of canvas screen

for(int i=0; i<5 ; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<5; j++) {
        x=x+10; //add 10 to value stored in variable x
        ellipse(x,y,10,10);
        line (x-5,y,x+5,y);
        line (x,y-5,x,y+5);
    }
    x=20;
    y=y+10;
}
```

Comment: Please only ask one question per post.

Answer (score 0):

The best thing you can do when you have questions like this is to get out a piece of graph paper and draw out some examples. What is the radius of the first circle? What is its X value? What is the radius of the second circle? What is its X value?

Keep drawing examples until you notice a pattern, and then you can use that pattern in your `for` loop.

Hint: I don't think you need a nested `for` loop (a `for` loop inside another `for` loop). I think you can do this with just a single `for` loop.

Comment: I managed to solve my first problem, thank you!
I used 
 ellipse (x,y,50-(4*i),50-(4*i));
  
  x=x+20;

I'm just having problems with the second problem. Any advice?

Comment: @JHaskins Stack Overflow isn't really designed for general "how do I do this" type questions. It's for specific "I tried X, expected Y, but got Z instead" type questions. I highly recommend that you **try something** and post a [mcve] in a new question post if you get stuck. Good luck.

Comment: @JHaskins I'll also say that the approach I outlined above is still your best friend. Get out a piece of graph paper and draw some examples until you notice a pattern that you can use in a `for` loop or a nested `for` loop. You might also try splitting each row into its own `for` loop, and then condensing that when you notice a pattern.